No funciona el dropdown en mi proyecto de angular 14
Estoy utilizando Angular 14 con bootstrap 5.2.3. Los estilos hasta ahora no me han dado problema, funcionaban bien ya que todo se veía como en la documentación oficial de bootstrap,el problema es a a la hora de utilizar un dropdown. Utilizando uno básico de la documentación este no funciona. En la consola me sale esto.
node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1895 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Popper__namespace.createPopper is not a function
at Dropdown._createPopper (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1895:1)
at Dropdown.show (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1812:1)
at Dropdown.toggle (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1799:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:2065:1)
at HTMLDocument.handler (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:388:1)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487:34)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:18)
at globalCallback (zone.js:1704:33)
**_createPopper @ node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1895
show @ node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1812
toggle @ node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:1799
(anonymous) @ node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:2065
handler @ node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:388
invokeTask @ zone.js:406
runTask @ zone.js:178
invokeTask @ zone.js:487
invokeTask @ zone.js:1661
globalCallback @ zone.js:1704
globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback @ zone.js:1729
Promise.then (async)
nativeScheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:561
globalCallback @ zone.js:1716
globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback @ zone.js:1729
Show 9 more frames
Show less
node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function
    at fe._createPopper (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:24353)
    at fe.show (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:22720)
    at fe.toggle (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:22532)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:27004)
    at HTMLDocument.s (node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js:6:4531)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487:34)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:18)
    at globalCallback (zone.js:1704:33)**

El código del dropdown es este
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

Y por otro lado tengo configurado de esta manera el angular.json
            "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"

        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]

En package-lock.json las versiones actuales son:
"bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
"jquery": "^3.7.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",

He probado con otros dropdowns a ver que puede ser y cambiando la versión de bootstrap a una versión anterior para ver si era problema de compatibilidad de versiones pero nada.
Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Intenta con /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

perfecto era eso, muchas gracias!

@alanfcm había visto que abría y había dado el problema por zanjado, pero resulta que va a medias, porque abre, pero no cierra, sabes que puede ser?
